# Shift list from given term

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Basically, I have a list here:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Given a specific term in the list (i.e. `"c"`), how can I make the list cycle through itself once, returning to the beginning once at the end?

Here's what I mean:

```
>>> list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> letter = "c"
>>> list = magicify(list, letter)
>>> list
["c", "d", "e", "a", "b"]
>>> letter = "a"
>>> magicify(list, letter)
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

Comment: This must be a homework assignment, I swear it has been asked before. Nevertheless, what have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: don't use `list` as an identifier it shadows the `list` type, secondly you could do this using numpy : `np.roll(l,len(l) - l.index('c'))`

Comment: Try this: `l[l.index(letter):] + l[:l.index(letter)]`

Comment: @EdChum: numpy seems excessive, but that's interesting.

Comment: @Linuxios I know but why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @EdChum: When the wheel is simple? :-/

Comment: @RobertB This question was definitely asked ad verbatim yesterday

Comment: @EdChum it was an example, I don't actually do that irl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
def magicify(list, letter):
    return list[list.index(letter):]+list[:list.index(letter)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about index().

Answer (score 0):

Solution with [**`itertools.cycle`**](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
from itertools import cycle

lst = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
pool = cycle(lst)

new = []
start = False
for item in pool:
    if item == 'c':
        start = not start
        if not start:
            break
    if start:
        new.append(item)

print new

>>> ['c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks but above answer is more concise

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for in the computer world is a circular shift. A common data structure that's used for that is a `deque`.

Assuming your elements are unique, or you have some other way to figure out the index of the "starting element".

```
from collections import deque

def magicify(mylist, letter):
    mydeque = deque(mylist)

    # Keep shifting elements on the right to the left until
    # you hit the chosen value (letter)
    popped = mydeque.pop()
    while (popped != letter):
        mydeque.appendleft(popped)
        popped = mydeque.pop()
    mydeque.appendleft(letter)

    return mydeque
```

You can make all of this more efficient, by using a deque the entire time, instead of a list. That way you can remove the first conversion step in the function.